# Text inside entities in Draft.js

Tags: reactjs

I've been playing with the Entity system in Draft.js. One limitation I see is that entities have to correspond with a range of text in the content they are inserted into. I was hoping I could make a zero-length entity which would have a display based on the data in the entity rather than the text-content in the block. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible when you have a whole block. As you can see in the code example this serialised blockMap contains a block containing no text, but the character list has one entry with an entity attached to it. There is also some discussion going on regarding adding meta-data to a block. see https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/129

```
"blockMap": {
  "80sam": {
    "key": "80sam",
    "type": "sticker",
    "text": "",
    "characterList": [
      {
        "style": [],
        "entity": "1"
      }
    ],
    "depth": 0
  },
},
```

Comment: Is it possible then for that entity to - for example - display as "Foo" even though the text of the block is empty?

Comment: absolutely! see here how it's done: https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#custom-block-components